# custom query set priting in django rest framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    UserId = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    GenreId = models.ForeignKey(Genre,related_name='genres',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    StartTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    Createdtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    IsBlocked = models.BooleanField()
    CounterLike = models.IntegerField()
    IsRepoCalulated = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Title

class TopicXReport(models.Model):
    TopicId = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    UserId = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Createdtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.TopicId, self.UserId)

class TopicXLike(models.Model):
    TopicId = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    UserId = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Createdtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.TopicId, self.UserId)

class TopicXVote(models.Model):
    TopicId = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    UserId = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    VoteType = models.BooleanField()
    status = models.BooleanField()
    IsBlocked = models.BooleanField()
    Createdtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.VoteType == True:
            Votetypebool = "for it"
        else:
            Votetypebool = "against it"
        return '%s "status" %s : %s -> %s' % (Votetypebool, self.status, self.UserId, self.TopicId)
```

i wanted to get api as like all topic fields with topicXlike and topicXreport total number of likes and report i am using django rest framework modelsearializer approach but not able to find spacific like how can i get output how i want output format is below

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "Title": "is it",
    "StartTime": "2020-04-04T16:09:37.781958Z",
    "Createdtime": "2020-04-14T15:31:11.459409Z",
    "IsBlocked": false,
    "totallike": 50, #this fields are coming from topicXlike  models
    "totalvotes": 50,#this fields are coming from topicXvotes models
    "IsRepoCalulated": 0,
    "UserId": {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "shilpa",
        "profile": {
            "Imagename": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/1mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg"
        }
    },
    "GenreId": {
        "id": 1,
        "Name": "Current Affairs",
        "Createdtime": "2020-04-14T15:31:11.343074Z"
    }
}
```

can anyone guide me to right direction i am little new to this thanks
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share the serialiser code and query of view file?

Comment: @AkashPagar i updated serializer in my question

Comment: share the query which you are executing on the model to retrieve the data. also while posting one question please try to share View Model and Controller so the problem referencing is well understandable.

Comment: ok this is all i didnt shere those becs those things are pretty basic next time i will keep those in mind @AkashPagar